# What is "condition of link to developer's website" condition in license

Tags: legal

I want to use following icons for my commercial website for free.

http://www.gettyicons.com/free-icon/112/must-have-icon-set/free-remove-icon-png/

According to to above link:

> Visual Pharm is the author of this icon. Visual Pharm will remain
>   owner of this icon and you cannot sell it, but you are allowed to
>   apply this icon in your commercial and non-commercial projects with
>   condition of link to developer's website.

But I cant understand following:

> with condition of link to developer's website

Do I have to show link of owner of icon site on my commercial website? If yes, where will I show their link?

Is there any other icons package that I can use commercially for free without showing their link on my site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have to show link of owner of icon site on my commercial website. If yes, where will I show their link.

Yes. If it is not specified you can place it anywhere you want as long as it is visible to users (and thus search engines). If you want to be nice you can place it in your footer although you can also bury it in an about page or a "credits" page.

> Is there any other icons package that I can use commercially for free without showing their link on my site?

Yes. A quick Google search will find you lots of them.